# Astro reference error when I follow the tutorial

Tags: astrojs

I have the following index.astro:

```
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation.astro';
<html lang="de">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator}>
<title>Pagetitle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <Navigation />
</body>
</html>
```

and following Navigation.astro

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
<a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
```

but I keep getting the error that Navigation is an unknown element pre coimpile warning and a reference error when npm run dev.
Can some1 pls ellaborate?

I tried running the above code and expected the Navigation to be rendered in the index page. But instead I get a reference error telling me Navigation is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigation.astro must include the HTML section in the body not in the frontmatter section

right :

```html
---
---
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
<a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
```

wrong missing x2 lines with `---`

```html
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
<a href="/blog/">Blog</a>
```

here is a reference to the tutorial to check again  https://docs.astro.build/en/tutorial/3-components/1/#create-a-navigation-component

see more details about the code fence (frontmatter) section here  https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-components/#component-structure

It is basically a separation of code from html astro syntax.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I thought the --- where comments:)